# NullPointerException in ElasticSearch bulk update

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add a suggest field to documents in my ES index using bulk update but I keep getting a NullPointerException as the response. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

using ES 1.1.1

command using curl:

```
curl -s -XPOST "http://www.example.com/test_index/entity/_bulk" --data-binary @tmp
```

inside tmp file:

```
{"update": {"_type": "entity", "_id": "fbf804af945d13d9b7c076948bc1bd19", "_index": "test_index"}}
{"lang": "js", "params": {"input_name": {"input": ["calcium"]}}, "routing": "434750445cdc9cea954399185e4b3da8", "script": "ctx._source.suggest = input_name"}
```

I get this response back:

```
{"error":"NullPointerException[null]","status":500}
```

But it works fine if I do a normal update:

```
curl -s -XPOST "http://www.example.com/test_index/entity/fbf804af945d13d9b7c076948bc1bd19/_update?routing=434750445cdc9cea954399185e4b3da8" --data-binary @tmp

{
  "script": "ctx._source.suggest = input_name",
  "params": {
      "input_name": {
          "input": [
             "calcium"
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

Here's what the mapping for entity looks like:

```
entity: {
    _parent: {
       type: post
    }
    _routing: {
       required: true
    }
    properties: {
       suggest: {
          type: completion
          analyzer: simple
          payloads: false
          preserve_separators: true
          preserve_position_increments: true
          max_input_length: 50
       }
       type: {
          type: string
          index: not_analyzed
          store: true
       }
       value: {
          type: string
          index: not_analyzed
          store: true
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your index mappings, you set routing to required so in the cmd part of your update you need to specify the routing parameter:

`{"update": {"_type": "entity", "_id": "fbf804af945d13d9b7c076948bc1bd19", "_index": "test_index",   **** --> "routing: "fbf804af945d13d9b7c076948bc1bd19" }}`